# APNG files not working in Xcode for iMessage Stickers?

Tags: xcode, animation, message, imessage, apng

I'm having trouble getting .APNG files to work - they preview correctly in Firefox (meaning when drag'n'dropped into a Firefox window, they animate the way they're supposed to) but when I drag'n'drop the same file into xcode, I see only the first frame. No animation. When previewing in a simulator, no animation - just a static sticker.

The same files animate correctly in an iMessage timeline when sent as attachments (like animated GIFs)..so the files are good.
Also, it's not a size issue - one of them is 16 Kb, and about 400x260. Some are larger in file size but smaller in frame size, none are over 350 Kb.

It's just Xcode that doesn't like them.

I know how to make animated sticker packs - I have two for sale already. For those, I used PNG sequences. I'm trying to use .APNG files because I'm getting way better compression.

I've used PNG Animator as well as apngasm to create the .APNGs, and they are all at or under 300 Kb in size, and under 600 pixels in size.

Is anyone successfully using .APNG files for creating animated stickers?

KM
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/markup-stickers/id1157027020?mt=8

UPDATE! GOT IT TO WORK!

I needed to import them as stickers, or static image files, and NOT as a sticker sequence, and also needed to name them .PNG and not .APNG.

Success! 
KM

Comment: Hey, you should answer your own question an mark it as "accepted" instead of editing your answer ;)